# Do not stop webviewer audio when the screen is locked?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make sure that when the phone is locked, the webviewer audio needs to keep playing. How can I do?

```
private WebView myWebView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.radioView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();//
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://websiteradio.eu");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you want to modify the webview source and recompile it and distribute it with your app (which is not reasonable).

By design anything "running" on a web page is stopped cold when the app leaves the foreground. This is a mobile device in most cases so you can imagine the impact on battery if anyone could leave pages running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

when your mobile screen goes off , your application goes into the on Pause state, 
  so you can use this.

```
@Override
 public void onPause() {
 try {
 Method method = WebView.class.getMethod("onPause");
 method.invoke(mWebViewHome);
} catch (Exception _) {
}
 super.onPause();
 }
```